# CORS working fine in jquery but not in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

My Sever side is php/mysql.

I am making Ajax call in webservice of another domain(Which have access control enabled for *)

```
    var postUrl = "http://logical-brains.com/elance_clone/test_login.php";
    var postData = {username : "tanmoy" , password : "123456"};
```

I tried by Simple jQuery :

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: postUrl,
  data: postData,
   dataType: "json",
  crossDomain: true,
  success: function(data){ console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); }
});
```

It worked fine and I got Status Code:200 OK with expected result.

BUT When I am trying by AngularJs ,  getting below Error :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://logical-brains.com/elance_clone/test_login.php. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

AngularJs Code :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}]);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    var postUrl = "http://logical-brains.com/elance_clone/test_login.php";
    var postData = {username : "tanmoy" , password : "123456"};
    $http({
        url: postUrl,
        method: "POST",
        data: postData,
         crossDomain: true
    })
    .then(function(result) {
            console.log("Success", result);
            $scope.someVal = JSON.stringify(result);
        }, 
        function(response) { // optional
            console.log("error "+response);
        }
    ); }; });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was in the problem. by deep search i get .. 
 For cross-domain requests, setting the content type to anything other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain` will trigger the browser to send a preflight OPTIONS request to the server. so if server does not allow it will throw errors. by default angular content type is `application/json` which is trying to send a OPTION request. but jquery default is 
`application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` so in your case for jquery is working and for angular it is not. try to overwrite angular default header . or allow it in server end. here is angular sample:

```
$http.post(url,data,{
              headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
            }

    });
```

see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/  content-type for detail